# Is 'is' correctly placed here: "Is X..., and if it is what the reason?"

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-structure

I would like to know if this sentence is clear, correct and sounds as native speaker sentence (I'm putting the doubtful words in bold):

> Is honey better than sugar, and **if it is** what the reason

Comment: You should focus on the last part instead: *what the reason*.

Comment: Ok, I'm not English native speaker, and I just want to be sure that it's ok, acceptable and not strange or something like that. :)

Comment: I see this might not be outright proofreading, and thus I didn't vote to close. I sense there may be others inclined to do that though, and I reached this through the review queue anyway. So it would pay if you reword your question and present your thoughts about it and what confuses you in a  more elaborate way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would re-punctuate it and add an "is":

- Is honey better than sugar—and if it is, what **is** the reason?

A shorter way to say this is:

- Is honey better than sugar? If so, why?